# Дан массив, например, 3 1 9 5 6 3 1 6 0 8. Нужно вывести так 1-319 2-195 3-956 4-563 5-631 6-316 7-160

Tags: c++

Дан массив, например, 3 1 9 5 6 3 1 6 0 8. Нужно вывести так

```
1-319
2-195
3-956
4-563
5-631
6-316
7-160
8-608
```

Вот мой код, помогите разобраться, что я делаю не так. Что-то нужно с вайлом сделать, но до меня не доходит

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

const int N = 10;

void main(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    int A[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        A[i] = rand() % 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << A[i] << ' ';

    cout << "\n\n";

    int k = 8;
    int *r, *t;
    int *p = &A[1];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++, p++){
        r = p - 1;
        t = p + 1;  

        while (k > 0 && k < 9){
            cout << i + 1 << " - " << *r << ' ' << *p << ' ' << *t << endl;
            k--;
        }                   
    }
}
```

Comment: Используйте <s>силу</s> отладчик

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Ничего с while-ом тут делать не нужно, поскольку он вообще тут не нужен (а также все эти переменные k, r, p, t тоже не имеют никакого смысла).

А нужено Вам просто в `for` менять i до `N - 2` и печатать i-й, i+1 и i+2 элементы массива (поскольку каждая цифра, которые Вы хотите печатать, это элемент массива `A`)

```
  for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; i++)
     cout << i + 1 << " - " << A[i] << A[i + 1] << A[i + 2] << '\n';
```

Вот и все.